# Hello World from cython wiki not working

Tags: c++, python, cython

I'm trying to follow this tutorial from Cython: http://docs.cython.org/docs/tutorial.html#the-basics-of-cython and I'm having a problem.

The files are very simple. I have a helloworld.pyx:

```
print "Hello World"
```

and a setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("helloworld", ["helloworld.pyx"])]
)
```

and I compile it with the standard command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I got the following error:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'helloworld' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c helloworld.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/helloworld.o
helloworld.c:4:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
helloworld.c:5:26: error: structmember.h: No such file or directory
helloworld.c:34: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject’
helloworld.c:121: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject’
helloworld.c:139: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:140: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_PyInt_AsLongLong’
helloworld.c:141: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLong’
helloworld.c:142: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:147: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:148: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:149: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:150: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:151: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:152: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:153: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:154: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:155: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:156: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:157: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:172: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:173: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:174: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:181: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:198: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:200: error: array type has incomplete element type
helloworld.c:221: error: ‘__pyx_kp_1’ undeclared here (not in a function)
helloworld.c:221: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:221: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[0]’)
helloworld.c:221: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:221: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[0]’)
helloworld.c:221: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:221: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[0]’)
helloworld.c:221: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:221: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[0]’)
helloworld.c:221: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:221: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[0]’)
helloworld.c:221: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:221: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[0]’)
helloworld.c:222: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:222: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[1]’)
helloworld.c:222: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:222: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[1]’)
helloworld.c:222: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:222: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[1]’)
helloworld.c:222: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:222: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[1]’)
helloworld.c:222: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:222: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[1]’)
helloworld.c:222: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
helloworld.c:222: warning: (near initialization for ‘__pyx_string_tab[1]’)
helloworld.c:237: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘inithelloworld’
helloworld.c:238: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘inithelloworld’
helloworld.c:305: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:313: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:379:21: error: compile.h: No such file or directory
helloworld.c:380:25: error: frameobject.h: No such file or directory
helloworld.c:381:23: error: traceback.h: No such file or directory
helloworld.c: In function ‘__Pyx_AddTraceback’:
helloworld.c:384: error: ‘PyObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:384: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
helloworld.c:384: error: for each function it appears in.)
helloworld.c:384: error: ‘py_srcfile’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:385: error: ‘py_funcname’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:386: error: ‘py_globals’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:387: error: ‘empty_string’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:388: error: ‘PyCodeObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:388: error: ‘py_code’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:389: error: ‘PyFrameObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:389: error: ‘py_frame’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:392: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromString’
helloworld.c:399: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromFormat’
helloworld.c:412: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyModule_GetDict’
helloworld.c:412: error: ‘__pyx_m’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:415: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_FromStringAndSize’
helloworld.c:420: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyCode_New’
helloworld.c:429: error: ‘__pyx_empty_tuple’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:440: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyFrame_New’
helloworld.c:441: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyThreadState_GET’
helloworld.c:448: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyTraceBack_Here’
helloworld.c:450: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_XDECREF’
helloworld.c: In function ‘__Pyx_InitStrings’:
helloworld.c:458: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘p’
helloworld.c:460: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘is_unicode’
helloworld.c:460: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘is_identifier’
helloworld.c:461: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘p’
helloworld.c:461: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8’
helloworld.c:461: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘s’
helloworld.c:461: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘n’
helloworld.c:461: error: ‘NULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
helloworld.c:462: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘intern’
helloworld.c:463: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘p’
helloworld.c:463: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyString_InternFromString’
helloworld.c:463: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘s’
helloworld.c:465: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘p’
helloworld.c:465: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘s’
helloworld.c:465: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘n’
helloworld.c:476: error: ‘__Pyx_StringTabEntry’ has no member named ‘p’
helloworld.c: At top level:
helloworld.c:485: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:494: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:500: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_PyInt_AsLongLong’
helloworld.c:516: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLong’
helloworld.c:538: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:553: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:568: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:583: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:598: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:613: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:628: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:643: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:658: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:673: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
helloworld.c:688: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have python and cython installed from Ubuntu 9.04 repositories. I can't figure why the compiler can't find Python.h.

I tried doing:

```
cython helloworld.pyx
```

and then compiling the result manually with gcc:

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.5 -o helloworld.so helloworld.c
```

and got the same exact error message.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you manually verified that `/usr/include/python2.6/Python.h` exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some package like `python_dev` or the like -- Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu) have long preferred to isolate everything that could possibly be of "developer"'s use from the parts of a package that are for "everybody"... a philosophical stance I could debate against (and *have* debated against, without much practical success, in mahy fora), but one that, sadly, can't just be ignored:-(

Answer (score 1):

Oh damn... forget it...

I forgot to install the dev packages.

Duh. Stupid. Sorry guys.

Comment: Which one exactly? Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me so stupid, when no official resource gives you some part of instruction about using something if they think it's self-evident. But how am I supposed to know this self-evident thing at my first attempt to learn it? Dah...
Anyway, what's the exact name of modules? In PyCharm search of packages for `python-dev` request I have 5 different modules.